# What is the difference between cat -b and cat -n and how cat -s does work

Tags: c, linux, unix, cat

I am currently developing a cat command in C and unix. My task is design cat -b and cat -s commands this time. However I have already have created other commands such as -t, -v, -n, -e. I got stuck at command -b as whenever I trigger the command it returns the same output what -n returns.

for example

```
cat -n hello.c

1  #include<studio.h>
2    int main() {
3      printf("hello");
4      return 0;
5   }

cat -b hello.c

1  #include<studio.h>
2    int main() {
3      printf("hello");
4      return 0;
5   }
```

My second question is how cat -s does work? as I again fired the command but the output displays a simple c file without any change.

for instance

```
cat -s hello.c

 #include<studio.h>
   int main() {

    printf("hello");

     return 0;
 }
```

Thanks in advance and for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a simple, six-line, file called `qq.in`, with two non-empty lines, two empty lines and another two non-empty:

```
a
b


c
d
```

The difference between `cat -n` and `cat -b` is that the former will number *all* lines while the latter will number only non-empty lines:

```
$ cat -n qq.in       $ cat -b qq.in
     1  a                 1  a
     2  b                 2  b
     3                    
     4                    
     5  c                 3  c
     6  d                 4  d
```

On the other hand, `cat -s` will collapse consecutive empty lines into a *single* empty line, as per the following (combined with `-n` so the effect is obvious):

```
$ cat -ns qq.in
     1  a
     2  b
     3
     4  c
     5  d
```

Note that the lines must be *truly* empty, these flags won't do what you expect if the lines contain a space or some other white-space. If you want to treat white-space lines as empty, you can filter them first with something like:

```
sed -E 's/^\s+$//' qq.in | cat -b
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately my output does not collapse blank lines in a single. It remains as it is, whatever code is written in a C file.

Comment: @Ravi, then there are a couple of possibilities. (1) The lines _aren't_ blank. (2) Your `cat` is broken with respect to `-s`.

Comment: I believe that both are the right possiblities, I am using a CIGWIN software on windows, is there any chance that the software doesn't support few commands?

Comment: @Ravi, Cygwin (cat --version giving `cat (GNU coreutils) 8.23 Packaged by Cygwin (8.23-4)`) supports all three just fine, I've just tested it. _Do_ note that the lines have to be _truly_ empty, if they contain spaces or tabs, they're considered non-empty.

Comment: Thanks for help and time, my file contains white spaces, that is the reason why all outputs are same.

Answer (score 3):

Question:

> What is the difference between cat -b and can -n and how cat -s does work

From the output of `man cat`:

> ```
>   -b, --number-nonblank
>           number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
>
>   -n, --number
>           number all output lines
>
>   -s, --squeeze-blank
>           suppress repeated empty output lines
> ```

When you use `cat -b`, the empty lines will not be numbered.

Here' what I see with a simple file:

`cat -b socc.cc`

```
     1  #include 

     2  int main()
     3  {
     4     return 0;
     5  }
```

`cat -n socc.cc`

```
     1  #include 
     2  
     3  int main()
     4  {
     5     return 0;
     6  }
     7  
     8
```

`cat -s socc.cc`

```
#include 

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: adding example of cat -s will make answer better.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  -b, --number-nonblank
>
>     number nonblank output lines
>
>  -n, --number
>
>     number all output lines
> ```

ref: [cat manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat)

and the second question, from man page:

> -s, --squeeze-blank
>
> ```
>     never more than one single blank line
> ```

you can implement this feature like this

1. read the file into a buffer
2. check the buffer whether it contains continuous blank lines, e.g "\n\n\n"
3. put them together, use only one "\n" instead of a set of it

Comment: Can you please provide me a code for that, I know how to read in buffer but am not able to squeeze those lines in a single line.